# Using useReducer results in Invariant Violation: Hooks can only be called inside the body of a function component

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I'm having some issues with latest React for React Native all development, since React introduced hooks I'm trying to play around with it, but to no avail. I'm having a Screen for RN to do some splash screen animations and it does not work with latest React, always giving me the above error. (it is working with React version `16.7.0-alpha.2`). Is there anything I'm doing wrong?

SplashScreen.js

```
import React, { useReducer } from "react";

const initialState = { currentIndex: 0 };

const reducer = ???;

const SplashScreen = (props: Props): ReactElement => {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialState);

  return (
    <GestureRecognizer
      style={styles.container}
      config={gestureRecognizerConfig}
      onSwipe={direction => dispatch({ type: direction })}
    >(...)</GestureRecognizer>
  );
};

export default SplashScreen;
```

AppNavigator.js

```
import { createAppContainer, createSwitchNavigator } from "react-navigation";
import SplashScreen from "./SplashScreen.js";

export default createAppContainer(
  createSwitchNavigator(
    {
      Splash: SplashNavigator,
    },
    {
      initialRouteName: "Splash",
    },
  ),
);
```

App.js

```
const App = () => (
  <View>
    {Platform.OS === "ios" && <StatusBar barStyle="default" />}
      <AppNavigator
        persistenceKey={navigationPersistenceKey}
        renderLoadingExperimental={() => <ActivityIndicator />}
      />
  </View>
);

export default App;
```

Comment: *Is there anything I'm doing wrong?* - you're not posting the code where SplashScreen is used. This is where the problem is. Please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: what's your `react-dom` version -- wait sorry, i can't read. what's your react native version?

Comment: My current React Native is `0.59.0` and React `16.8.4`

Comment: https://reactjs.org/warnings/invalid-hook-call-warning.html

Comment: Make sure your react and react-dom are using the same version

Comment: I have the name version of `react` and `react-dom` and getting the same problem